# Tolerance of pin in Scissors

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, tolerance

I'm currently designing scissors, and I have to describe the tolerance and fits of the parts. What kind of tolerance must be used for the pin holding the two blades together, though allowing for rotations? (i.e. clearance, transition, or interference).

Thank you very much for your insights!

Comment: Looks like homework - so please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't think they really set a tolerance for that. Mostly, the two blades are just riveted together. You can't really set a tolerance with that. Putting a sheet of foil between the blades makes them have a little play. I suppose that's how it's done. It's far more important to get properly curved blades, so they mesh together. Straight blades don't cut(well), but are often found on cheap scissors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looked at my kitchen scissors; clearance approximately of +.001"/+.003".

Comment: Seems a bit much to extrapolate from one pair of scissors into all scissors.  Would you consider [edit]ing your answer and expanding upon it?

Comment: The question asked for the tolerance, my answer provided the tolerance.